# Adding inputs into local storage multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-local-storage

The point is that i want to save some data into localstorage multiple times by some dropdown menu and few inputs (for now). I can get all values from the inputs and i see it in console.log. I would like to save that inputs into localstorage as object (clicking button Spremi), and after changing options and one more click to save another object into lcoalsotrage etc.

[image]

browse.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Browse">
  <ion-content>
  <select id="vrstaribe" ng-model="selekt" ng-options="r as r for r in ribe" selected>
   <option value="">Vrsta ribe</option> 
  </select>
   <label class="item item-input">
   <input id="tezina" type="number" placeholder="Tezina">
   </label>
   <label class="item item-input">
   <input id="mamac" type="text" placeholder="Mamac">
   </label>
   <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="spremi()">Spremi</button>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

contollers.js

```
.controller('SpremiCtrl', function($scope) {
var ulov = {vrstaribe: '', tezina: '', mamac: '' };
var popisulova = [];

$scope.ribe = ["Saran", "Stuka", "Som"];

$scope.spremi = function() {

var vr = document.getElementById('vrstaribe');
var rib = vr.options[vr.selectedIndex].text;
var tez = document.getElementById('tezina').value;
var mam = document.getElementById('mamac').value;
console.log("Riba : " + rib + '\n' + "Težina : " + tez + '\n' + "Mamac : " + mam);
ulov.vrstaribe = rib;
ulov.tezina = tez;
ulov.mamac = mam;
popisulova.push(ulov);
console.log(ulov);

localStorage.setItem('ulov', JSON.stringify(ulov));
var vrati = localStorage.getItem('ulov');

//console.log('Ulov: ', JSON.parse(vrati));
console.log(ulov);

}

})
```

Comment: what error does it throw now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will solve your problem, but you have a lot of other problems and you are not coding in an "angular way".

```
$scope.spremi = function() {

    var vr = document.getElementById('vrstaribe');
    var rib = vr.options[vr.selectedIndex].text;
    var tez = document.getElementById('tezina').value;
    var mam = document.getElementById('mamac').value;
    console.log("Riba : " + rib + '\n' + "Težina : " + tez + '\n' + "Mamac     : " + mam);
    ulov.vrstaribe = rib;
    ulov.tezina = tez;
    ulov.mamac = mam;

    var fromStorage = localStorage.getItem('popisulova') || '[]';
    var vrati = JSON.parse(fromStorage);
    vrati.push(ulov);

    localStorage.setItem('popisulova', JSON.stringify(vrati));

    console.log(ulov);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ngStorage`, please refer to https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

```
    angular.module('app', [
        'ngStorage'
    ]).controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $localStorage, $sessionStorage){

   // put your code here!

});
```

you also can refer to [How to use ngStorage in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33036026/how-to-use-ngstorage-in-angularjs)