# Restore scope when browser back button is clicked

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular for rendering view like this:

```js
var app = angular.module("demo", []);



app.controller('demoCtrl', ["$scope",function ($scope) {
  
  $scope.current_step = 1;
  
  $scope.step_two = function(){
        $scope.current_step = 2;
    };
  
   $scope.step_one = function(){
        $scope.current_step = 1;
    };
  
}]);
```

```css
.button {
    background: #fb6648;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 18px 0px;
    max-width: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none!important;
}

.area {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="demo">

  <div ng-controller="demoCtrl" id="demoCtrl">
      
     <div ng-if="current_step==1">
       <span class="area" >Step One</span>
        <a class="button" ng-click="step_two()" >go to Step Two</a>
      </div>
    
     <div ng-if="current_step==2">
       <span class="area">Step Two</span>
        <a class="button" ng-click="step_one()" >Back to Step One</a>
      </div>
    
    
  </div>
 </body>
```

i want this button to work when browser back and froward button are pressed.
i tried changing hash but it didn't worked.

Comment: you need to use angular router

Comment: yeah i know but i have already build this project without angular router. don't want to include it for this small functionality.

Comment: you lose the page when go backward or forward

Comment: @azad isn't there any way so i could change the hash in url or manipulate browser history so that browser restores the previous state or at least fires an event so that i can restore the scope myself.

Comment: @GauravSrivastava If you want to manipulate the state of browser history, use can see this
https://github.com/browserstate/history.js

http://johan.driessen.se/posts/Manipulating-history-with-the-HTML5-History-API-and-AngularJS

Comment: basically i have a variable in scope which decides what div needs to be shown. you can see the code i have provided in question.

Comment: @GauravSrivastava what you've tried so far now ? And what problem still you're getting ?

Comment: @Loading.. i solved the problem by setting $location.hash and then tracking hash change event.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you need to store the value of scope as cookie.

That can be done as shown below.

> **Case-1: Cookies** More [$cookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies)

Provides read/write access to browser's cookies.

```
angular.module('cookieStoreExample', ['ngCookies'])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$cookieStore', function($cookieStore) {
  // Put cookie
  $cookieStore.put('myFavorite','oatmeal');
  // Get cookie
  var favoriteCookie = $cookieStore.get('myFavorite');
  // Removing a cookie
  $cookieStore.remove('myFavorite');
}]);
```

> **Case-2: ngStorage** More [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage)

An AngularJS module that makes Web Storage working in the Angular Way.

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ["ngStorage"])
    app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $localStorage, $sessionStorage, $window) {
        $scope.Save = function () {
            $localStorage.LocalMessage = "LocalStorage: My name is XXX.";
            $sessionStorage.SessionMessage = "SessionStorage: My name is XXX.";
        }
        $scope.Get = function () {
            $window.alert($localStorage.LocalMessage + "\n" + $sessionStorage.SessionMessage);
        }
});
```

More help

[how-to-use-ngstorage-in-angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33036026/how-to-use-ngstorage-in-angularjs)

Comment: how i am gonna restore the value of cookie on browser back button press?

Comment: You can check the condition if the cookie is checked not reset it again, that way you can do that.

Comment: would it be the best solution?

Comment: @GauravSrivastava It depends on your requirement, you need to choose that which option / solution is best for you.
If you've multiple pages (view) for steps, you can defined multiple different controllers for each and use ngStorage to keep track value of scope. Generally if we need to store any value in cookie or track it via browser back / forward button, we use localstorage in jQuery.

Comment: You can navigate the user to a new state using history api's push state method. Later when the user clicks on back button history api's onpopstate event will be called, here you can use cookie or local storage to reset the scope value.

Comment: @GauravSrivastava I've updated my answer. Can you show me your view and how you're planning to render a different views from a single controller ?

Answer (score -1):

Use `$localStorage`,

```
    angular.module('myApp')
         .controller('MyCtrl',function($scope,$localStorage){

            window.onhashchange = function() {

                console.log("triggered");

                if($localStorage.user != null){

                    //get value from $localStorage and set it to scope variable 
                    $scope.user = JSON.parse($localStorage.user);
                }
            }
    });
```

In someother controller you need to set `$localStorage.user` value as

```
$localStorage.user = JSON.stringify({'name':'Geo','age':22});
```

If it is not null you can reassign it to the `$scope.user` variable.

Comment: it will not work because if i change the hash it will fire the hash change event when i change the hash from code or when back button is pressed.

Comment: Handle it depends on your hashchange condition.. This answer will do restoring the scope value.

Comment: don't think that in real project i  have just two $scope.current_steps variable which i can handle from from if/else.